# Calculate average of array elements using MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a collection of documents such as:

```json
{
    _id: 5,
    responses: [
        {
            staff: false,
            timestamp: 1000
        },
        {
            staff: true,
            timestamp: 1500
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a function (using `$function`) used to apply some custom logic with the `responses` array:

```js
const diffs=[];
let current;
for (let i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
  if (i+1>=responses.length) break;
  if (!current && !responses[i].staff) current = responses[i];
  if (!current) continue;
  const next = responses[i+1];
  if (!next.staff) continue;
  diffs.push(next.timestamp - current.timestamp);
  current = undefined;
}
return diffs;
```

which basically returns array of numbers like `[500, 1000, 10]` etc. It can also potentially return an empty array (`[]`).

I want to basically combine all arrays into one (say one document returns `[5, 10]` and the next one returns `[1, 2]`, the result would be `[5, 10, 1, 2]` -- order doesn't matter) and then calculate the average using `$avg`.

I was reading MongoDB docs and found [`$concatArrays`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/), so to my understanding the process should be:

1. Calculate diffs for each document, which will end up with an array like `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [], ...]`
2. Use `$concatArrays` on the value from step 1
3. Use `$avg` on the array from step 2

How should I go about making step 1? The only part I'm not sure about is how to hold a variable in the first grouping stage with the result returned from `$function`. I understand I need to do something like this:

```
aggregate([
    {$group: {diffs: {$function: {...}}}}
])
```

However, I get the error `MongoServerError: unknown group operator '$function'`.

Comment: Not clear what you want to do, maybe simple `{$avg: "$responses.timestamp"}`. Otherwise have a look at [$reduce](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit `responses.timestamp` is a Unix timestamp, basically what I want to do is calculate an average of an array after concatenating it -- is there something specific not clear?

Comment: For a document, if all `responses.staff` are `true` then `"$function"` returns `[]`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Yep, that's right. Check the answer I posted if you're interested in further clarification. Basically, the goal is to find the first "non-staff" (staff=false) response, and then continue searching forward for the next response that is staff=true, then calculate the time difference. Alternatively, if all `responses.staff` are `false` then the result is also empty.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting it working the way I wanted. Sorry if there was some confusion over the data to anyone reading the original question -- the basic gist of the problem was, for each document the function calculates an array which are all numbers (like `[1, 2, 3]`), and I wanted to make one big array with all the numbers combined from all the documents, then calculate an average with it.

I got it working by first calculating the array for each document (`diffs`), unwinding the array, using `$push` to push each element of the array into a new one, and then finally using `$avg` on the created array. Hopefully this helps someone with a similar problem down the line.

```
db.tickets.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            responseTimes: {
                $function: {
                    body: function(responses) {
                        const diffs=[];
                        let current;
                        for (let i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
                            if (i+1>=responses.length) break;
                            if (!current && !responses[i].staff) current = responses[i];
                            if (!current) continue;
                            const next = responses[i+1];
                            if (!next.staff) continue;
                            diffs.push(next.timestamp - current.timestamp);
                            current = undefined;
                        }
                        return diffs;
                    },
                    args: ["$responses"],
                    lang: "js"
                }
            }
        }
    },

    {$unwind: "$responseTimes"},

    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,

            responseTimes: {
                $push: "$responseTimes"
            }
        }
    },

    {
        $project: {
            avgResponseTime: {
                $avg: "$responseTimes"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) says:

> Executing JavaScript inside an aggregation expression may decrease performance. Only use the `$function` operator if the provided pipeline operators cannot fulfill your application's needs.

A starting point to achieve the same natively with an aggregation pipeline could be this one. I did not spend much time in testing, but this would be the direction.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      responseTimes: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$responses",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: { $not: "$$this.staff" },
              then: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", [ "$$this.timestamp" ] ] },
              else: {
                $cond: {
                  if: { $gt: [ { $size: "$$value" }, 0 ] },
                  then: {
                    $concatArrays: [
                      { $slice: [ "$$value", { $subtract: [ { $size: "$$value" }, 1 ]  } ] },
                      [ { $subtract: [ "$$this.timestamp", { $last: "$$value" } ] } ]
                    ]
                  },
                  else: null
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      avgResponseTime: { $avg: "$responseTimes" }
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ie6IL8atLX-

A different approach is to use `input: { $range: [ 0, {$subtract: [{ $size: "$responses" }, 1]} ] },` and then access the elements with `{ $arrayElemAt: [ "$responses", "$$this" ] }`, maybe see [this example](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-53503) which is a similar use-case.

Comment: This works perfectly, although it breaks on cases like these. Would you happen to know why? (The responseTimes array should be empty in this case, since there's no sequence that occurs with one `staff=false` response followed by a `staff=true` one): https://mongoplayground.net/p/q6YrUBXrfo8